# How to open Microsoft Project file on SharePoint 2013 in client application

Tags: sharepoint-2013

We have an on-premise SharePoint 2013 farm, and we have a few `.mpp` files stored in a library.

`.xls` and `.doc` files in the library were opening in the respective Web Apps, but the `.mpp` files were not.

I was getting an alert asking if I wanted to allow the website to open an app on the computer.
On selecting `Allow`, it was showing a prompt for getting an app for `ms-project` from the Store.

I changed the library to open all files in client applications, but the behavior for `.mpp` files persist.

Curious case is that if I open 'View properties' and click on the link, it opens in the client application.

How can I force the `.mpp` files to always open in the client?

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this with a very simple change in the view.

We unchecked the default `Name (linked to document with edit menu)` column and replaced it with `Name (linked to document)`.

Now we are able to open the `.mpp` file in the client application.